# View animation... the ImageView disappears when I switch to next activity

Tags: android-imageview, android-animation

I have this weird problem I can't seem to solve..

I have a View animation that translates an ImageView with an image of a cloud plugged into it.
This ImageView moves from right side of the screen to the left and then repeats indefinitly.
I use an XML to set the parameters for that and then onWindowFocusChanged() I start the animation.
I have a OnClickListeners that listens for a click on that screen and then I get the next Activity started.
The problem is, once I click the screen, the ImageView with the animation disappears and only then, about half a second later, the next Activity starts.
Is there a way to keep the ImageView from disappearing ?
I tried using setFillAfter(true) and setFillEnable(true) but it did not help.

Here is some code that is related to this:

In onCreate():

```
cloud1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloud1_iv);
cloud1Mov = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.cloud_anim);
cloud1Mov.setFillAfter(true);
cloud1Mov.setFillEnabled(true);
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" 
android:fromXDelta="80%p"
android:toXDelta="-100%p"
android:repeatCount="-1"
android:duration="40000" />
```

This is the onWindowFocusChanged():

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    cloud1.startAnimation(cloud1Mov);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting old posts by me here...
So, it seems that adding the fillAfter="true" attribute in the XML's header solved this for me